# Python: "subject" not shown when sending email using smtplib module

Tags: python, smtplib

I am successfully able to send email using the smtplib module. But when the email is sent, it does not include the subject in the sent email.

```
import smtplib

SERVER = <localhost>

FROM = <from-address>
TO = [<to-addres>]

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

message = "Test"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

How should I write "server.sendmail" to include the SUBJECT as well in the email sent.

If I use, server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message, SUBJECT), it gives error about "smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused"

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Attach it as a header:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)
```

and then:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Also consider using standard Python module [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email) - it will help you a lot while composing emails. Using it would look like this:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = TO
msg.set_content(TEXT)

server.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: in 2021, this adds the subject into the body of the message unfortunately.

Comment: @TheoF No, it does not. The example constructs a small and trivial but perfectly valid RFC5322 message, still in 2021. But as the answer suggests, you _really really_ want to use the `email` module to construct the input message if it's at all less trivial than this.

Comment: I have a question tho, why two linebreaks, why won't three work, with three I get no subject at all, why does it have to be two, I can't find any documentation on this anywhere as the main docs use the email module

Comment: @publicstaticvoidMain As repeated multiple times already, don't do that. Three newlines should work fine _per se_ but adds a silly empty line to the top of the body of the message. But you really want to use the `email` library, or **really** understand email and MIME before you start assembling messages yourself.

Answer (score 45):

This will work with Gmail and Python 3.6+ using the new "EmailMessage" object:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content('This is my message')

msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = "me@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "you@gmail.com"

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("me@gmail.com", "password")
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Python 3.6+. Thanks!

Comment: The port number and the authentication details depend on which server you are connecting to. Common variations include using port 587 (or, for internal servers, 25, without SSL) and/or doing `ehlo` before - or even twice, before and after - `login`.

Comment: Works for Outlook too! Also if your server doesn't require SSL, you can use this instead: smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 365, timeout=5)

Answer (score 19):

try this:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'sender_address'
msg['To'] = 'reciver_address'
msg['Subject'] = 'your_subject'
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.sendmail('from_addr','to_addr',msg.as_string())
```

Comment: What about the body of the message? Where does that go?

Comment: I ended up following this to put in the body https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5

Comment: In the current python version, this functionality is now managed by email.message.MailMessage.

Comment: This is now obsolescent, and should not be used for new code. Prior to Python 3.6, this was what you had to use (except then too you would have wanted your message to also have a body).

Answer (score 7):

You should probably modify your code to something like this:

```
from smtplib import SMTP as smtp
from email.mime.text import MIMEText as text

s = smtp(server)

s.login(<mail-user>, <mail-pass>)

m = text(message)

m['Subject'] = 'Hello!'
m['From'] = <from-address>
m['To'] = <to-address>

s.sendmail(<from-address>, <to-address>, m.as_string())
```

Obviously, the `<>` variables need to be actual string values, or valid variables, I just filled them in as place holders.  This works for me when sending messages with subjects.

Comment: I am getting the following error:    from email.mime.text import MIMEText as text
ImportError: No module named mime.text

Comment: @nsh - with what version of Python?  I'm using 2.6.6 on this particular install.  It's entirely possible that it's in a slightly different place in 3.x.

Comment: The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably review the current [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 6):

```py
import smtplib
 
# creates SMTP session 

List item

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 
# start TLS for security   
s.starttls()
 
# Authentication  
s.login("login mail ID", "password")
 
 
# message to be sent   
SUBJECT = "Subject"   
TEXT = "Message body"
 
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)
 
# sending the mail    
s.sendmail("from", "to", message)
 
# terminating the session    
s.quit()
```

Comment: This does not seem to add any new information over previous answers.

Comment: I liked the answer as it uses only smtplib module which was the original question

Answer (score 5):

See the note at the bottom of smtplib's documentation:

`In general, you will want to use the email package’s features to construct an email message, which you can then convert to a string and send via sendmail(); see email: Examples.`

Here's the link to the examples section of `email`'s documentation, which indeed shows the creation of a message with a subject line. https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

It appears that smtplib doesn't support subject addition directly and expects the msg to already be formatted with a subject, etc. That's where the `email` module comes in.

Comment: Like the accepted answer demonstrates, you can construct a valid RFC5322 message from simple strings if you know what you are doing, or are following an example exactly. For anything more than that, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to include it in the message:

```
import smtplib

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP HTML e-mail test

This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

code from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Comment: One observation: from, to and subject fields, for example, must be at the VERY BEGINNING of the variable "message", for example, or else, the fields will not be interpreted as it must be expected. I had the experience with just inserting "Subject" field, not at the beginning of the variable, and the message came to the receiver's mailbox with no subject. Cheers.

Comment: can you please add, "sender" and "receivers" variables in your code. they are being passed into smtpObj.sendmail(), but aren't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In case of wrapping it in a function, this should work as a template.

```py
def send_email(login, password, destinations, subject, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)

    server.login(login, password)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, message)

    for destination in destinations:
        print("Sending email to:", destination)
        server.sendmail(login, destinations, message)

    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
from = "myemail@site.com"
to= "someemail@site.com"

subject = "Hello there!"
body = "Have a good day."

message = "Subject:" + subject + "\n" + body


server.sendmail(from, , message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the 'No Subject' issue, follow these steps:

- Update the server details, port, sender, and receiver information in the code provided below.
- Update the HTML content in the code.
- Test the code after making these changes.

```py
    import smtplib
    from datetime import date
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    today = date.today()
    reportdate = today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    #your server details here
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("yourserver.com", port) # update your org server 
    
    sender_email = "mailtrap@example.com" # update email 
    receiver_email = "new@example.com"  # update email 
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "Daily Monitoring Report - " + reportdate
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email
   

    # write the HTML part
    html ="<HTML> <style> table, td, th {  border: 1px solid;}table {  width: 50%;  border-collapse: collapse;} </style> <BODY> Hi All, <br>" + \
    "<br><span style='color:Blue'>  statistics summary </span>" + \
    "<br>" + \
    "<br>" + "Please contact me for additional information required"+"<br>" + \
    "</BODY></HTML>"

    part = MIMEText(html, "html")
    message.attach(part)
    
    try :
        # send your email
        with smtplib.SMTP("yourserver.com", port) as server:   # update server 
        #server.login(login, password)
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
        print('Sent')
    except Exception as error:
        print(f" error while sending email - {error}")
```