# Sending email incl. Subject field ,using Python SMTP

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I used `server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)` to send automated emails using python.

How can I add an email subject to the mail?
I tried to look in SMTP documentation and didn't find any documentation for that.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552229/adding-subject-to-the-email-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: "subject" not shown when sending email using smtplib module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232088/python-subject-not-shown-when-sending-email-using-smtplib-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python) :

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
import smtplib

gmail_user = user
gmail_pwd = pwd
FROM = user
TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
SUBJECT = subject
TEXT = body

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.close()
    print 'successfully sent the mail'
except:
    print "failed to send mail"
```

Comment: it works OK. from what i understand- the subject string is part of body message ? can you explain how to modify sender's name (and not guyd@gmail.com) ?

Comment: You can set FROM to anything you want.

Comment: OK, I thought it have to be same as sender for reply.