# Python smtplib ''Subject'' why doesn't it print any subject. I've tried almost anything now

Tags: python, email, smtplib

The email sending code works fine without problems, but it prints all of it in the message field. I've basically tried everything the last 3 hours. Any advice guys?

```
import smtplib

fromaddr="xxxxx@xxx.com"

toaddr="xxxxx@xxxx.com"

message = '''\\
         ... From: xxxxx
         ... Subject: testin'...
         ...
         ... This is a test '''

 password="xxxx"

subject="this is supposed to be the subject"

server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,message,subject)
server.quit()
subject = "this is supposed to be the subject"
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the issue is? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: The thing is when I run the program it sends a mail to the mailadress I want it to send to. That works fine! but it has ''no subject'' in the mail so the only thing you can see when you click the mail is the message inside the mail but without a subject'' Do you know where I'm going with this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232181/5686598

Comment: Could you show how to attach it, and what the code would look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the message using MIMEText has always worked for me.
Here is how you can use it:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# message body goes here
message = '''\\
         ... This is a test '''

msg = MIMEText(message, 'plain')
msg['Subject'] = "this is supposed to be the subject"
msg['From'] = "xxxxx@xxx.com"
msg['To'] = "xxxxx@xxxx.com"

server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It will send email with the intended subject text.

Comment: Fair enough. +1