# how to send SQL query results to email in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

The code below sends an email to my outlook. But, the email is empty and the column names in the query are printed in subject line and the email body is empty and I don't see the query results.

```
import smtplib

import pyodbc

import pandas as pd

myconn = pyodbc.connect('Driver='{SQL Server}',host='', database='',user='',password='', Trusted connection='yes')

query = """SELECT *;"""

df = pd.read_sql(query, myconn)

remail = "sendto@gmail.com"

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-outlook.com', 587)

smtpObj.ehlo()

smtpObj.starttls()

smtpObj.login('from@gmail.com','PASSWORD')

smtpObj.sendmail('from@gmail.com', remail, 'Subject:Query results \n' +df.to_string())

smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python email body is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214990/python-email-body-is-empty)

Answer (score 2):

use yagmail lib. to send email

```
import smtplib
import yagmail
import pandas as pd

import mysql.connector


host= '*****'
user= '*****'
passwd= '******'
db= '********'

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host=host,
     user=user,
     passwd=passwd,
     database=db
     )
myconn =mydb

query = """SELECT * from sa_user;"""

df = pd.read_sql(query, myconn)

receiver = "*******@gmail.com"

print(df)
yag = yagmail.SMTP("*******@gmail.com")
yag.send(
        to=receiver,
        subject="Verify your email",
        contents=df.to_string(), 
        )

print("done")
```

this is my inbox screenshot

[image]

Comment: Results are getting printer in terminal. But, I'm not receiving any email still.

Comment: when you execute this code yagmail ask to enter password of sender email. so are you entered that password?

Comment: It didn't ask me anything. also, unable to import yaml

Comment: yaml not required you can run without yaml. remove this import yaml.

Comment: but, it's not working for me. also, i'm using outlook not a gmail account.

Comment: which domain are you using ? if is it gmail then please turn on  "Less secure app access" from here https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/lesssecureapps?pageId=none   of your sender account

Comment: i'm using outlook

Comment: try to do with some gmail id's. it will be work. or use https://libraries.io/pypi/yagmail-outlook

Comment: same as your's.. just the query and email changed to check if it works.

Comment: yes it works for me i can show you the latest screenshot of my inbox.

Comment: screen shot of my code : https://photos.app.goo.gl/AaBSE4j6nWWyaAbi6

Comment: screenshot of inbox of my email :https://photos.app.goo.gl/Z2ty3zSTDoEN9PDx7

Comment: In that case you can use smtplib to send email.